# Django Rest Framework: How to set a field to null via PATCH request?

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

I have a `Model` and a `ModelSerializer` with this field:

models.py:

```
leftovers_from = models.ForeignKey('DayPlanning', null=True, blank=True, related_name='extra_for', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

serializers.py:

```
leftovers_from_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=DayPlanning.objects.all(), source='leftovers_from', write_only=True, required=False)
```

Now I can perfectly fine create a new object for this model using a POST request (both with or without this field being `null`/`None`/empty.)

However when I try to update the field using PATCH I can only update it with a different value (a PK of the Foreign model). I've tried passing `null`, `''`, `0` and `-1` to `leftovers_from_id`, however the result is either `This field cannot be empty` or `PK 0 not found`.

How do I clear this field using a PATCH request?

Thanks!

Comment: post your view.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Note that `required` means the field may be omitted for creation or "full" update. Patch bypasses the `required` fields to achieve a partial update.

Therefore you'll need to set [`allow_null`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#allow_null) argument to True:

```
leftovers_from_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
    queryset=DayPlanning.objects.all(),
    source='leftovers_from', write_only=True,
    required=False, allow_null=True,
)
```

Then you should be able to PATCH with:

```
{'leftovers_from_id': null}
```

Comment: Worked, thanks! blank=True, null=True, required=False, allow_null=True, Damnit Django how many declarations of emptiness do I have to make :p
Nevertheless your explanation makes sense, thanks again!

Comment: The thing here is you explicitly define the serializer field so it breaks DRY a bit.

Answer (score 1):

To clear the relation, you should set the value to `None`. Since you specifically mentioned `PATCH` methods, make sure you're aware of the `partial` argument as well: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#partial-updates